# Clear template cache after update sale on Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, cache, craft2

How can I clear products template cache after update sale ?
Because product price don't change ...
Thank you.

Comment: Sale prices are not cached, I would double check your sale conditions and post more details if you can.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely the issue is not the prices not updating, but the sale conditions as Luke mentioned.

In theory, Craft will automatically clear template caches when an element within the cached region is updated (note one trap is this process of deleting stale template caches runs as a job task, so may not happen absolutely *immediately*...give things 30 seconds or so before you check them).

If things don't seem to be working for whatever reason, you can clear caches manually using the Craft control panel.

Thus, in case it is somehow cache related:

Craft 2: Control panel -> settings -> clear caches

[image]

Craft 3:

There are now console commands to clear caches (run `./craft` on its own and it will list all of the available commands e.g. `./craft clear-caches/template-caches`

Or, you can of course still use the control panel-> utilities -> clear caches

[image]